# r difference each element with group mean

Tags: r

I have a data frame that contains two types cols - numeric and factor.
How can I difference each element with group mean in a new column.
I can find group mean with 'aggregate', but I can't extract diff between each element and it's group mean (different lenght).

Comment: When asking for programming help, it's expected that you include a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) with sample input data and desired output.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can easily do it with a basic linear model (I removed the intercept so that the value of each effect is the group mean in the model summary). Let's take the example of `data(mtcars)`, the variable `am` being your grouping factor and `mpg` your numeric variable:

```
mtcars$am <- factor(mtcars$am)
lm(mpg~am-1, mtcars)$resid
```

The residuals of this model are *by definition* the difference between the element and its group mean.